# Readding all key batch wise using stack exchange Redis client

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

i am using StackExchange.Redis (2.1.58) , i write below code by using cursor .

```
Dictionary<string, string> keyResult = new Dictionary<string, string>();

                var Server = Connection.GetServer(Connection.GetEndPoints()[0]);

                long current_cursor = 0;

                int next_cursor =-1;
                long page_size = 10;

                while(next_cursor!=0)
                {   
                        var allkeys = Server.Keys(RedisCache.Database, argKeyPattern, 10, 0, next_cursor==-1 ? 0 : next_cursor);


                        var cursor = ((StackExchange.Redis.IScanningCursor)allkeys);

                        foreach (var key in allkeys)
                        {
                            if (current_cursor == cursor.Cursor)

                            {
                                keyResult.Add(key, RedisCache.StringGet(key));

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                next_cursor = Convert.ToInt32(cursor.Cursor);
                                current_cursor = next_cursor;

                                break;

                            }
                        }
                    }
```

this code works fine , my question is there any other approach to read keys from Redis batch wise in more efficient way ?
Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/main/docs/KeysScan.md)

> The Keys(...) method deserves special mention: it is unusual in that it does not have an *Async counterpart. The reason for this is that behind the scenes, the system will determine the most appropriate method to use (KEYS vs SCAN, based on the server version), and if possible will use the SCAN approach to hand you back an IEnumerable that does all the paging internally - so you never need to see the implementation details of the cursor operations. If SCAN is not available, it will use KEYS, which can cause blockages at the server.

From first looks, `KEYS` command should be avoid. However, the library already fix that for you by using `SCAN` if the command is available. So I think you're good here.

if SCAN command is not available so `Keys()` will fallback to using `KEYS` command

`SCAN` command is available in version 2.8++

Comment: but currently its not apply paging no matter what page size i give its give all record , and thats the reason i need to use cursor

Comment: @Dilip check the version of redis server maybe? it says it does use scan if available

Comment: @Dilip updated answer. since you're using redis 2.1, SCAN command is not available so it fallback to KEYS command

Comment: my bad, 2.1 is the lib version. but check the redis server again anyway

Comment: Hi @TuanAnhTran  yes my lib version I given let me check my server version, Will update you . thanks

Comment: Hi @TuanAnhTran Please find version details in server 

redis-server -v
Redis server v=4.0.9 sha=00000000:0 malloc=jemalloc-3.6.0 bits=64 build=9435c3c2879311f3

redis-cli -v
redis-cli 4.0.9

Comment: @Dilip in that case, you probably want to file issue in the lib's repo https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis

Comment: Hi @TuanAnhTran  yes its look like lib issue , as i checked  direct  with redis-cli  and there scan command work as expected . and lib also show  it does use scan if available , but will see if there is any solution on git for that , thanks for ur time